# Rails navbar color not changing completely Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm new in rails, so far I'm stuck trying to change the color of the navbar.
I have read almost everything about the subject and I haven't seen anything like my case.
As you can see in the pictures, the navbar changed to the color I wanted but for some reason the corners are still in black and also the background of my dropdown menu still in black.

Well I cannot upload pictures because I'm new here.
The github repository is at https://github.com/nanurbina/janus.git
I hope someone can give me a hand.

Here is my code on _navigation.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <%= link_to 'Janus BPO', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand' %>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <%= render 'layouts/navigation_links' %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and the code on the css.scss

```
  @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
  @import "bootstrap";
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: inherit;
  background-color:#2d246d;
  border-color:#2d246d;
  color:#2d246d;
  }
 .navbar-collapse
    {
    background-color:#2d246d;
    border-color:#2d246d;
    color:#2d246d;
     }
.navbar-inverse .container {
   background-color:#2d246d;
   border-color:#2d246d;
   color:#2d246d;
   }
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here.  Why are all of your colors (background, border, and text) the same value for all three CSS rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `navbar-inverse` with `myNavbar` on your html and add the following to your CSS:

```
.myNavbar   {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color:#222;
    border: 1px solid #333;
 }
```

Just change the color codes to what you want and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! It solved the problem of the black color on the corners. But now I have other color on the text, when i hover the mouse, etc.. 
I changed the values but is not working. I tried to follow the same logic (to change the name to the other classes) but is not working. Only the class navbar-brand is responding to the changes.
It will be great if you advise what's wrong.

Comment: add this to your css:

`.myNavbar li a {
        color: #FFF;
  }
.myNavbar li a:hover, focus, active {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: none;
  }`